# Why does my code ask to define a variable that can't be defined?

Tags: python, nameerror

So I have a piece of code that is a text classifying neural net. I'm trying to modify it so it can classify user's input. This is the original:

```
def SpeechToTextAndClassification(sentence, show_details=False):
results = think(sentence, show_details)

results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD ] 
results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) 
return_results =[[classes[r[0]],r[1]] for r in results]
print ("%s \n classification: %s" % (sentence, return_results))
return return_results

SpeechToTextAndClassification("yes")
```

And this is the modified version:

```
def SpeechToTextAndClassification(command, sentence, show_details=False):

results = think(sentence, show_details)

results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD ] 
results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) 
return_results =[[classes[r[0]],r[1]] for r in results]
print ("%s \n classification: %s" % (sentence, return_results))
return return_results

print ()
print("run check")
talkToMe("I am ready, sir") #text to speech
command = myCommand()
print(command)
SpeechToTextAndClassification(command, sentence, show_details=True)
```

The issue is that it gives an error on sentence- The sentence is the part of the training data as seen here:

```
training_data = []
training_data.append({"class":"yes", "sentence":"Yes "})
training_data.append({"class":"yes", "sentence":"Yeah"})
training_data.append({"class":"yes", "sentence":"Yup "})
training_data.append({"class":"yes", "sentence":"Yes it does"})
```

With the following error:

```
line 319, in <module>
SpeechToTextAndClassification(command, sentence, show_details=True)
NameError: name 'sentence' is not defined
```

How would I change it so it can use the user's input instead? Thanks!

Comment: can you format your code please

Comment: Why do you expect `sentence` to be defined? You never defined it anywhere

Comment: @e4c5 Please specify

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it was defined in the training_data_append part

Comment: There is no variable named `sentence` defined there...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I was able to fix my own code. I changed command (the speech to text) to sentence, then redeclared it like so:

```
def SpeechAndTextClassification(sentence, show_details=False):
    results = think(sentence, show_details)

    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD ] 
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) 
    return_results =[[classes[r[0]],r[1]] for r in results]
    print ("%s \n classification: %s" % (sentence, return_results))
    return return_results

sentence = myCommand()
sentence #executing the function 
talkToMe("hello world")
SpeechAndTextClassification(sentence)
```

Works like a charm now!